# Triggering an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a target website where there is the following dropdown menu.

```
<select class="categories-options" data-level="1" name="level1-option" id="level1-option" required="">
  <option value="">default</option>
  <option value="p1" data-href="/callback/p1">P1</option>
  <option value="p2" data-href="/callback/p2">P2</option>
  <option value="p3" data-href="/callback/p3">P3</option>
</select>
```

When an item is selected from the menu, it triggers a "change" event and a function is called when this event happens. I have debugged the event using Chrome and you can see the debugging output when I selected an item from the dropdown menu. I have taken a screenshot from the debugger.

Now, let me explain what I am trying to do. I use a javascript function to select an item from the dropdown menu using the following code:

```
var id= document.getElementById('level1-option');
setSelectedValue(id, "p2");
$('#level1-option').trigger("select");
```

In the last line, I try to trigger the same event that happens originally in the webpage as if I manually selected the item. however, it doesn't trigger anything. |I see in the debug output that the  event is triggered by class. I have tried many different things but didn't work. Could anyone shed some light on this issue? How can I trigger the same event that happens in that webpage using jquery or javascript?

[image: Chrome debugger output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
$('#level1-option').trigger("select");
```

...will trigger an event called `select` (which isn't related to the value of a form field change), but the event you stopped on in the debugger is `change`, not `select`:

[image]

If you want to trigger the `change` event, trigger the `change` event:

```
$('#level1-option').trigger("change"); 
// Difference is here -------^
```

---

Side note: Because you're using jQuery, your code can be simpler, you dont need the `getElementById` or the `setSelectedValue`:

```
$('#level1-option').val("p2").trigger("change");
```

Comment: Well, I already tried select, change, onChange but they don't just work. What do you think about srcElement in the debug window? maybe my selector is not correct?

Comment: @Dundar: The `select` event would be irrelevant here (it doesn't relate to the value changing). There is no `onChange` event. The event is `change`. It certainly looks like you have the right selector for the element, and jQuery's `trigger` does fire the change event. I suggest stopping the debugger on your code and making sure the element exists as of when you're trying to update it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#level1-option').trigger("change");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please see my comment below.

Comment: You can add this in the document ready function of JQuery

`$('#level1-option').on("change",function (){  DO_YOUR_STUFF_HERE  });`

This will trigger everytime you change the item selected in the dropdown